# Behaviors of unicode escape sequence in comments

Tags: java, unicode

According to "Core Java Vol. I" by Cay Horstmann:

[image: quote]

So, the below code should not work:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] arg2) 
    {
        // \u00A0 is a new line  
        char alpha = 'a';
        System.out.println("abc" + alpha);
    }
}
```

But it works.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code works because the character [`\u00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) is a non-breaking space and **not** a newline character.

Most likely what has happened is that the author has made a typo and actually *meant* to type [`\u000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm), which *is* a line feed character and does indeed break as expected.

Comment: And indeed, the code compiles as presented, but does not compile if `\u00A0` is changed to `\u000A`.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. It's typo and when i write \u000A it works. Thanks.

Comment: But if we write \n like: //  \n is a new line. Should it be error?

Comment: @NickSilicon `\n` isn't a newline in a java comment, it's simply a backslash followed by an n, so it should be completely fine.

Comment: But, when we write code: System.out.print("abc\n" + alpha); It gives new line.

Comment: @NickSilicon And that's fine, because `"abc\n"` is a `String` and not a comment. Comments aren't subject to the same rules that strings are.

Comment: I see. So, \n is present in java but it acts differently in String and comments(//). In comments \n will be simply a String.

Comment: This actually has little to do with String escape sequences.  The `\u` notation is not a string escape;  it is a general escape notation permitted for any character in the entire file, including newlines and content of comments. The compiler processes such escapes before evaluating the source at all.  `String s = "abc";` and `\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067 \u0073 \u003d \u0022abc\u0022;` are exactly the same code.